# How do I cancel searching for a multiplayer match?

Tags: splatoon-3

I started queuing up for a multiplayer match in Splatoon 3 only to realize I needed to take care of something first. How do I cancel searching for a multiplayer match?

[image: matchmaking]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When matchmaking first starts there should be an option to cancel by holding the - button.

[image: option to cancel matchmaking]

The cancel button usually goes away after a few seconds and won't appear if you've queued for a rematch. If the cancel button isn't available, you can still disconnect without a penalty by closing the game from the home menu or turning on airplane mode.

Answer (score 0):

When I do that mistake I jump out to the Switch menu and close application.

Haven't been able to find a button to do so yet. And my shut down the app technique seems to work. Never came back with a ranked loss because it put me in a game while I had closed the app or something like that.